# "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine" How to solve this?

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have a asp.net website which is using MYSQL DB.
Not frequently but for some users when they type the site URL sometimes it give 404 error. But if he refresh the page site is working.

When I check the error code here is it

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message : Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
StackTrace :    at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
Message : Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream has failed.
StackTrace :    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.AuthenticationFailed(Exception ex)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(Boolean reset)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at DBAccess.DBAccess.openConnection()
   at DBAccess.DBAccess.getData(String query, MySqlCommand myParametrizedSqlCommand)
   at DAL.UserLogin_Dal.GetLoginData(String email)
   at BLL.UserLogin_Bll.ValidateLogin(String email, String passWord)
   at HRMS.intro.SignIn()
   at HRMS.intro.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
Message : Reading from the stream has failed.
StackTrace :    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
System.IO.IOException
Message : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
StackTrace :    at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.HandleOrRethrowException(Exception e)
   at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Message : An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
StackTrace :    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

"An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"
Here is the main error.

Nothing changed. Only thing happned was we had to redeploy the website in a new server.
What is the issue here?